# Can I connect an old HDD with Windows through my laptop with Ubuntu and boot from it?

Tags: windows, ubuntu, hard-drive, multi-boot, operating-systems

I've got a 3.5" HDD from my old desktop PC (which stopped working) with Windows 7 on it. I have some old photos on it and wanted to get them,
so I bought an HDD-to-USB adapter from AliExpress. Anyway, it didn't work with 3.5" HDD.

So I'm wondering if I bought a new one that works, can I boot the Windows 7 OS on my HDD through USB on my laptop that runs Ubuntu?

Comment: No need to boot an old OS to get to old files. If there is no encryption involved then Ubuntu should be able to just mount the filesystem and read (copy) files.

Comment: @KamilMaciorowski just like a regular usb drive?
At first i wanted to just access the files, now i want to know if i can use it to boot Win, not just access the files

Comment: No, you can't. Windows doesn't boot from external drives, except Windows To Go which is something you certainly don't have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the hard drive is functional and you put it in a working USB adapter, Ubuntu should be able to read the contents of the drive.  As mentioned in a comment, this is assuming the hard drive is not encrypted using BitLocker, Veracrypt, Windows File Encryption, etc.  Simply boot your laptop to Ubuntu, attach the drive, and you will be able to use Dolphin (the default Ubuntu file manager), or whatever file manager you choose, to see the file system.

As for booting off the drive, it is *possible*, but not likely to work.  That will depend entirely off your BIOS options and hardware.  However, there is no need, as you can simply follow the directions in the first paragraph.

Comment: Just 2 quick notes: 1. *Nautilus/Files* is the default file manager in Ubuntu and many flavors; *Dolphin* is the default in Kubuntu and typically on anything with KDE. 2. **No, Windows will NOT boot from an external drive**, not really dependent on BIOS/UEFI or hardware. Try for yourself if you don't believe me (you won't even be able to install it there but you can try the same thing that the OP wants to do) then come back and tell us which BSoD you got ;)

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia You are probably right about the file manager.  I forgot I was using Kununtu.  However you can boot from an external drive.  I dont need to try it, as I have done it many times.

Comment: You mean you have booted *plain Windows 7 installation* from an external drive?